# CommandLink is not called anymore after click on commandButton

Tags: jsf, button, jsf-2

There are a list with 100 "Favs" on it. It only shows 10 when the page loads. When I click on "Show More Favs" it shows 10 more Favs.

What's weird about it, it's after I click on Show More Favs, clicking on Remove from list, it's not calling the method in the backBean.

My backBean is ViewScoped.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="fav">
 <h:form>
  <h:commandLink styleClass="someStyle" title="Remove from list" action="#{bean.remove(fav.id)}"/>
 </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
<h:form>
 <h:commandButton value="Show More Favs" action="#{bean.showMore}" >
  <f:param name="moreFav" value="10" />
  <f:ajax event="action" render="@all" />
 </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the usage of multiple forms and the `render="@all"`. If you re-render *another* form from inside an ajax form, the viewstate of the *another* form will get lost.

You need to change the code so that only the *content* of another form is re-rendered:

```
<h:form id="otherform">
 <h:panelGroup id="list">
  <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="fav">
   <h:commandLink styleClass="someStyle" title="Remove from list" action="#{bean.remove(fav.id)}"/>
  </ui:repeat>
 </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
<h:form>
 <h:commandButton value="Show More Favs" action="#{bean.showMore}" >
  <f:param name="moreFav" value="10" />
  <f:ajax event="action" render=":otherform:list" />
 </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```